# I just cant solve this linear equation system..

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, gaussian-elimination

I need your help to solve this equation:

$$5000ps= 1500+ 100pw$$
$$1420pw= 3200+ 1000ps$$

$$80pa=   5050+ 2000ps+ 100pw + 20pa$$

I'm searching for **pa**, **pw** and **ps**.

Could someone help me in solving these linear equation.

**Note** - ***pw, pa and ps are variables***

Comment: pa, pw, ps are variables or what.

Comment: 3 equations, 3 variables, just chuck them into some 3x3 linear equation solver online.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You've included the "ordinary-differential-equations" tag, but I don't see any type of differential equation at all, even if the $pa,pw,ps$ are meant to be some type of differential values, with what you've shown apparently being $3$ linear equations in $3$ unknowns. Please update your question to either show how it involves a differential equation or remove that tag. Also, while you're at it, please also add what you've tried before, especially anything you had difficulty with, plus possibly other context like where the question comes from. Thanks.

Comment: yes pa,pw and ps are the variables.

Comment: I tried to change the equation but I couldnt manage it.

Comment: What exactly is the difficulty? Label the equs (1), (2), (3). Then (1)+5(2) gives pw=5/2. Then use (1) to get ps=7/20, then use (3) to get pa.

Answer (score 2):

The given equations are -

$$5000=1500+100$$ 
$$1420=3200+1000$$
$$80=5050+2000+100+20$$

---

### You can solve for $pa, ps \ and \ pw$ in the following way

- Multiply the second equation with $5$.
- Then solve first and second equation.
- You will get $pw = 2.5$.
- Now substitute $ pw = 2.5$ in either the first equation or the second equation to get $ps$. You will get $ps = 0.35$
- Substitue the value of $ps$ and $pw$ in the third equation to find the value of $pa$.

I would suggest you to try solving for $pa$ on your own. If you need any help, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your system as:

$-100 (pw) +5000 (ps) =1500$

$1420 (pw) -1000 (ps)=3200$

$-100 (pw) -2000 (ps) +60 (pa)=5050$

We could use a method called [Gaussian Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination), to make the process systematic (even without a computer). We need to create an augmented matrix of coefficients separate the right hand side by a vertical bar and perform row and column operations to convert the matrix to an equivalent matrix with only the value  1 in each diagonal entry and zeroes everywhere else. This makes the variables easy to get. The steps are as follows:

[image]

$pw=2.5$
$ps=0.35$
$pa=100.$

I have used [This tool](https://onlinemschool.com/math/assistance/equation/gaus/), since typing all this is too much for me.

Comment: A mistake in the last equation ($100$ instead of the correct $-100$).

Comment: @metamorphy, thank for the gentle warning. Fixed.